# Is it possible to have section titles inside paragraphs?

Tags: sectioning, paragraphs, titlesec, sections-paragraphs

Is there a way to have section titles that are inside paragraphs, especially when using `titlesec` package?

The `runin` style and others cause a paragraph break after the input line. What I am aiming for is just a normal paragraph that has titles inside itself.

Comment: You could use \vspace{-4ex}, for example, to remove the space between the previous text and the section name.  Other people will probably have more sophisticated answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Disclaimer** This is a way to go but please don't do that since the output is not really *reader-friendly*.

If you do not want to modify anything else in the section titles style, you can add the following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\gobblepars{%
    \@ifnextchar\par%
        {\expandafter\gobblepars\@gobble}%
        {}}
\makeatother

\newenvironment{mysec}[1]{%
\stepcounter{section}%
{\bfseries\noindent\thesection\hspace{0.5em} #1\hspace{0.5em}}%
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\thesection \hspace{0.5em} #1}%
\sectionmark{#1}}%
{\gobblepars \hspace{0.5em}}

\begin{document}

\begin{mysec}{First Section Title}
\blindtext
\end{mysec}
\begin{mysec}{Second Section Title}
\blindtext
\end{mysec}

\end{document}
```

The `gobblepars` command is coming from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7170248).

You will get this kind of output

[image: Output]

**NOTE** I am not entirely sure about the part for the `sectionmark` and all kind of advise would be welcomed. Concerning the TOC it seems to work properly as well as the section numbers.

Comment: I already answered this question in a similar way (I've deleted it), but the OP wants (I don't know why) no line break between two sections... I'm undeleting it for a few minutes, so you will see what he/she answered.

Comment: @karlkoeller See my edit. It should better fit the will of the OP.

Comment: Please add in the answer: "Please don't do that"... BTW: I forgot to delete mine again. Done now.

Comment: @LudovicC. I came up with a similar thing but it really did not work in all the needed aspects. Your answer does everything correctly, including `sectionmark`. Thank you! Regarding reader friendliness, I use this kind of titling to provide verse numbers as superscripts so it's not such a huge aesthetic problem.

Comment: @karlkoeller Thanks! And you know I am not at all a guru in LaTeX, I just try to bring my contribution to this amazing website where I got so much for my previous projects. If I could help only one person that would already be nice in my opinion.

Comment: @karlkoeller I won't say anything but keep encouraging rookies and this website will become even more efficient, and who knows maybe some days rookies will become gurus... ;)